# Analog Clock - PHP with Javascript - date function

Tags: javascript, php, html, date, time

For my personal challenge I am trying to re-create a lo-fi house room. In the room I would like to display a analog clock with the current time, completely programmed with PHP.

I am currently able to "hardcode" it through if statements, but now I would like to move the minutes section every minute at the right time. I couldn't find it on internet, so I hope you can help me out here! Somehow I need to make this a for loop, but I don't know how to iterate through the css section.

Would appreciate any help!

```
            <div class="clock">
                <?php
                    $m = date("i");
                    echo date("h:i:s");
                    
                    //Need to become a for/while loop
                    if ($m == 14){
                        echo '<div id="mins" style="transform: rotate(60deg);"</div>'; 
                    }
                ?>
                <div id="mins"></div>
            </div>
```

```
.clock{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: 20%;
}

#mins{
    height: 60px;
    width: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: black;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform-origin: bottom center;
}
```

Comment: i bet you will solve this more easing when using DateTime!!

Comment: I think you are looking for a Javascript solution. PHP is not able to return something every second to the browser. PHP only returns one server-rendered page when the client requests it.

Comment: yes, use php to display initial time and then you make an javascript interval that updates the clock´s cursor every minute

Comment: Thanks guys...! How can I connect the PHP time with javascript?

Comment: Edit the question from PHP to PHP with Javascript please. I will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks! Just changed

Answer (score 1):

My solution with Javascript for an analog script. No PHP needed.

`index.php`

```
<div class="clock">
    <div id="hours"></div>
    <div id="minutes"></div>
    <div id="seconds"></div>
</div>
```

`javascript`

```js
const updateInMS = 1000;

// Get the HTML elements from the page.
const clock = document.getElementsByClassName('clock')[0];
const htmHours = document.getElementById('hours');
const htmMinutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
const htmSeconds = document.getElementById('seconds');

// Start the timer
startTimer();

function startTimer() {
    // Trigger the tick function that loops the clock
    tick();
}

function tick() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Retrieve the date
        const now = new Date();
        const hours = now.getHours();
        const minutes = now.getMinutes();
        const seconds = now.getSeconds();

        const secondsInDegrees = (360 * seconds) / 60;
        const minutesInDegrees = (360 * minutes) / 60;
        const hoursInDegrees = (360 * hours) / 12;

        htmHours.style.transform = 'rotate(' + hoursInDegrees + 'deg)';
        htmMinutes.style.transform = 'rotate(' + minutesInDegrees + 'deg)';
        htmSeconds.style.transform = 'rotate(' + secondsInDegrees + 'deg)';

        tick();
    }, updateInMS);
}
```

`css`

```css
.clock {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: 20%;
}

.clock div {
    height: 60px;
    width: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    /* UPDATED THIS TO FIXED: */
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: black;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#hours {
    background: black;
}

#minutes {
    background: red;
}

#seconds {
    background: blue;
}
```

Hope you like my solution.

Comment: Side note: since you're not reassigning any values, it'd make more sense to use `const` instead of `let`.

Comment: When I try it, it gets the second and minute hands right, but the hour hand is off. Do you get the correct results?

Comment: I see you've already corrected the hour calculation to 12 divisions. Now the hand should point to the correct hour.

Comment: That is correct @El_Vanja Thankyou for the heads up, credits to you.